# Scala multiple import formatting

Tags: scala

Can anyone tell whether we should format like this:

```
import scala.collection.{Seq, List}
```

or like this:

```
import scala.collection.{ Seq, List }
```

according to the convention.

Without space examples:

- Idea is formatting without spaces by default.
- http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/119
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Import
- [Scala import multiple packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935409/scala-import-multiple-packages)
- https://github.com/odersky/dotty/blob/master/tests/neg/arrayclone-new.scala#L2
- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/scaladoc/scala/tools/ant/Scaladoc.scala#L15
  Effective Scala:
  http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Formatting-Imports

With space examples:

- Scalariform is formatting with spaces by default.
- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/0b47dc2f28c997aed86d6f615da00f48913dd46c/src/interactive/scala/tools/nsc/interactive/Picklers.scala#L9
- https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-testkit/src/test/scala/akka/testkit/AkkaSpec.scala#L9

Cheers

Comment: By looking in the scala repo in github I see that they prefer the second one. (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/0b47dc2f28c997aed86d6f615da00f48913dd46c/src/interactive/scala/tools/nsc/interactive/Picklers.scala)

Comment: I can tell the opposite with https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/scaladoc/scala/tools/ant/Scaladoc.scala

Comment: According to twitter's Effective scala it's the second.
http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Formatting-Imports

Also IntelliJ default Scala formatting is set for the second variant too, if it makes any difference for you.

Comment: Life is too short for this type of concern IMHO.

Comment: just go with whichever you prefer... But be consistent!

Comment: @I.K. Life is too short for being bothered by merge conflicts at each autoreformat.

Comment: @Tyth I guess you wanted to say the first one

Comment: @Joan, you can ignore white spaces when doing merges - Git has this option, if you are using it.

Comment: I think scalariform just changed the default to _not_ use  spaces ;)
https://github.com/daniel-trinh/scalariform#spacesaroundmultiimports

Answer (score 3):

The only concrete docs I can find are this http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Formatting-Imports which favours

```
import scala.collection.{Seq, List}
```

However the scala source itself uses `import scala.collection.{ Iterator, AbstractIterator }` https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/io/BufferedSource.scala

In Intellij, if you have

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{Seq, List}
import scala.collection.immutable.{ Set, Map }
```

and you run 'Reformat Code' you get:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{Seq, List}
import scala.collection.immutable.{Set, Map}
```

Bottom line - there doesn't seem to be a very hard and fast style rule.

Comment: Agreed. Akka also uses spaces within the braces:
https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-testkit/src/test/scala/akka/testkit/AkkaSpec.scala#L9